# Can't add description to OneDrive folders

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm posting a create item http request the to the graph api ("\children") to create a folder under a groups files,  but I'm getting the following error:

> "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
>       "message": "The property 'description' does not exist on type 'oneDrive.item'.

Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."

It does not allow `description` to be part of the the request body json, even though the documentation says it is a read-write property on the item type.

Please help anyone!?:) The description field could be really valuable to store additional info about a folder or file.

Comment: Can you update your question with details on the request you are making including the body of the request AND the timestamp and client request id in the response that you get back please?  That will help us get further with this request.

Comment: Body: {"name":"Test","description":"test","folder":{},"@name.conflictBehavior":"rename"}

Comment: Response: request-id: c3551f4f-4201-47a5-b657-64a9db0b2a79
client-request-id: c3551f4f-4201-47a5-b657-64a9db0b2a79
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"SliceA","ScaleUnit":"001","Host":"AGSFE_IN_2","ADSiteName":"AMS"}}
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
OutBoundDuration: 84.2788
Duration: 88.9988
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2015 16:14:14 GMT
Content-Length: 378

Comment: "innerError": {
      "request-id": "c3551f4f-4201-47a5-b657-64a9db0b2a79",
      "date": "2015-12-17T16:14:15"

Comment: Can you try the same operation, but without specifying a description please?  Does that work?

Comment: Yes, without the description it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *description* property isn't support for OneDrive for Business right now, which is why this call fails. If you create a folder without the *description* property the call should succeed. I've made updates to the documentation to remove the *description* property from the docs until it's supported for OneDrive for Business.

Comment: Any timeline indication? Will there be other options of adding metadata to folders and files in OneDrive?